# Error showing when Delete image in laravel

Tags: laravel

I want to delete images that I store in server,

I store images like this

```
 $image1 = $postData['img']['0']->store('public');
 $Add->Img1 = str_replace('public/', '', $image1 );
```

images save in public/storage folder[image]

I display images like this

```
<img src="{{ asset('/storage/'.$add->Img1)}}">
```

so I need to delete this image using a tag like this

```
<a href="{{route('deleteImg',[app()->getLocale(),'id'=>$add->Img1]) }}" class="btn">Remove</a>
```

this is my route

```
Route::get('/deleteImg/{id}', 'AlladdsController@DeleteImg')->name('deleteImg');
```

this is my controller for delete images

```
public function DeleteImg (Request $request, alladds $alladds)
{
   $img= request('id');

   if(Storage::delete('/public'.'/'.$img)) {
         return   'file is deleted';
     }
     else {
        return   'file is not deleted';
        }
  return redirect()->back();
}
```

but this code is not working, what I want to do correct this code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your route is injecting the id into the method `DeleteImg()`, but you have a different field catching the injected id.

This routing:

```
Route::get('/deleteImg/{id}', 'AlladdsController@DeleteImg')->name('deleteImg');
```

pushes id into the method as the argument after `$request`.

I don't know what `alladds` is, and it doesn't seem to be used, so I suggest following Laravel convention and re-write the method input like so:

```
// Note lower case to match route method and std.
public function deleteImg (Request $request, $img){ ... }
```

This will inject whatever you are sending into the route right into the method.  This will fix the mismatch error (if that was even an error -- not sure as you didn't say what the exact issue was).

Also - note you are calling the asset from `storage` directory and then trying to delete the image from `public`- these are two different places, and may well be the cause of the error - perhaps one of these locations is incorrect and thus you are trying to delete (or call) from an area where it doesn't exist.

Comment: AlladdsController@DeleteImg receiving Image name, but deleting function not working, I think may be image path issue ,

Comment: Yes - I think so.  See the last part of my answer - you are going from storage to public - one of those is the correct answer.  Set the correct path for both and I think this solves it.